# Managing queue delivery in sendmail

Tags: sendmail

I'd like sendmail to process the queue in a slow fashion.

In order to do that, Is there a way to configure it so it sends N messages every T minutes ?

Thanks

Comment: Just curious: why sendmail? On an other thought: what's the task you are actually trying to solve?

Comment: I have a single rather small mailing list, and don't think majordomo is worth the configuring effort (or is it?)

Comment: Could you describe problems with sending your mailing list? Because IMHO solution you want to implement is "suboptimal" in most cases.

Comment: I started to do a [small mailing list in Exim](https://github.com/janoszen/SimpleEximMailingList) a few years back. It doesn't have rate limiting options, but that should be [easy to add](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-access_control_lists.html#useratlim). It's not sendmail, but Exim may prove to be a lot more handy and flexible at stuff like this.